# Tridiagonal matrices and vector space dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, tridiagonal-matrices

"The set of all $n$ × $n$ tridiagonal matrices forms a 3n-2 dimensional vector space."(Wikipedia)

I'm familiar with what a tridiagonal matrix is but I'm not sure why this specifically is true.

I was wondering why this is the case, and how to prove it?

Comment: In a sense, we can think of the "dimension" of a space as referring to the number number of scalar quantities that are required to uniquely specify an element of the space. For a tridiagonal matrix, we need to specify the $3n-2$ non-zero entries in order to uniquely determine such a matrix.

Comment: Well, $n+(n-1)+(n-1)=3n-2$, so that's trivial. I don't know of any use of that fact.